# NoClassDefFoundError with Apache POI on Android

Tags: android, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, eclipse-adt

I am experiencing a NoClassDefFoundError for an application. The errors says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
```

The problem is that I have tried every solution I can find without success. I know the problem is with the Import/Export settings but I can't figure out what is the problem.

In my team, I am responsible of the model in the model-view-controller architecture, so I first develloped a basical PC version before porting it to Android. This one was working like I charm so I suspect that I missed the part where Eclipse transfers the librairies on the phone.

1: Here is a view my Package Explorer right now:

[image: Package Explorer]

As you can see, the POI-3.9 librairy is in a folder in my project. Every .jar are requiered.

2: If we look in the project properties, this is what we can see in the Librairies tab:

[image]

I made a custom user librairy as suggested on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary).

3: If we go in the Order and Export tab:

[image]

I know this is the most important part.

1. If I try to place my librairy everywhere without checking the box, I always get the NoClassDefFoundError no matter how.
2. When I check the box and do the same thing, Eclipse freezes while launching the application and I need to terminate the program with the Task Manager.

My question is: do you see the reason why is it  not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that box to make the library available to your project. By exporting those jars you are making them available to any project that references that library.

What do you mean by "Eclipse Freezing" ? Is it just a new emulator taking a long time > 30 mins to start ? That would not be unusual on an average windows box. If not, check the error logs .

Comment: Thanks Sheldon. It was really helpful. It helped me to find the solution and that I had to continue digging even if my computer was bugging. First: I have found that my computer was freezing because of a "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 (this is what it was saying on other computers). I solved my issue by removing all my imported librairies of Apache POI, deleting it and creating another by adding the required JARs one by one to make sure I get the only ones that I needed. It seemed like there was only one or more jar in poi that was causing a Dalvik format error.

Comment: Well done for solving that - you used a good method for a difficult problem. Not sure I deserve the points - you can always write your own  solution and accept that instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve using these steps:

1. Check LogCat
2. Find out which class is not found. Searching that class on
   Google for POI api will tell you in which jar that file is.
3. Download that jar file and include in your project.